# Informatica: How to use union and minus operator

Tags: informatica

I'm new to informatica . Please help how to use the below sample containing union minus operator.

```
SELECT item_id 
FROM table1 
WHERE sys_id='SPP' 
MINUS (
    SELECT pi_id 
    FROM table2 
    WHERE pi_id NOT IN ('SWS','SWT')
    UNION 
    SELECT DISTINCT itemgrp 
    FROM table2 
    WHERE pi_id NOT IN ('SWS','SWT') 
)
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What are you hoping that code will do? How is it letting you down?

Comment: I want to implement it in informatica..This is a part m stuck into...can I use this union operator in source qualifier or expression or have to go for union transformation...pls help

Answer (score 0):

You can implement MINUS with joiner Transformation, UNION with Union Transformation, NOT IN with Filter Transformation and so on. But I don't think creating these many object makes sense for this simple task.

Rather , you should push the whole query to database.

Thanks !!